# Merge multiple rows into one cell

Tags: tables

How can I write the code of this sample of table. I use the multirow command but I can't remove the midline of them. [image]

Comment: You can put tabulars inside tabulars.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I suppose you used `\hline`s.  From the second one, replace them with `\cline{2-7}` (your table, apparently, has 7 columns).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and time

Comment: Please note that it is better if you show us code that reproduces your issues (it doesn't have to contain your real data if you don't want to, but should show the general behaviour). If we get a minimal code example that we can compile we can help you much better.